# Single .tex file, multiple .bib files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

I am writing a collaborative document in which each author
edits a `main.tex` file and provides a `<author>.bib` file (no `\include`, no `\input` ... I know it's not the ideal choice but it was not my decision).

What we are having issues with is that we can't manage to have multiple bibliographies at the end of each chapter (`chapterbib` requires to use `\include`, it mention something in the manual to have a single file, but it is not very clear to me how to do it)

A minimal example is like this:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Author 1}
\section{author 1 section}
..something
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliography{author_1}

\chapter{Author 2}
\section{author 2 section}
..something
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\pagestyle{plain}
\bibliography{author_2}

\end{document}
```

author_1.bib

```
@article{lagrange1772essai,
  title={Essai sur le probleme des trois corps},
  author={Lagrange, J.L.},
  journal={{\OE}uvres},
  volume={6},
  pages={229--324},
  year={1772}
}
```

author_2.bib

```
@article{euler1741solutio,
  title={Solutio problematis ad geometriam situs pertinentis},
  author={Euler, L.},
  journal={Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae},
  volume={8},
  pages={128--140},
  year={1741}
}
```

It might happen that author_1.bib and author_2.bib contain the same reference (with the same id key probably).

Any hint how to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward when using the `biblatex` package. 
It is somehow compatible with `natbib`, but if you can ditch it all together, it is even better.

With `biblatex` you can list different bib files to your latex document and assign them to specific section considered for the separate bibliographies (`refsections` in biblatex terms) with `\addbibresource[]{}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{author_1}
\addbibresource{author_2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{author 1 section}
\begin{refsection}[author_1]
...
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\chapter{author 2 section}
\begin{refsection}[author_2]
...
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

I advise you to read the full doc of `biblatex`, you can also automatically affect `refsection` to `chapter`, `part`, or `section`, without having to specify the environment.

Comment: Damn, you were faster with very same idea:) Why didn't you put `\chapter` inside `refsection`?

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer but I get the error "! LaTeX Error: File `logreq.sty' not found." when using the biblatex package..

Comment: What is your LaTeX distribution and what backend do you use? I've tried it with MikTeX 2.9 full and biber.

Comment: I use texlive shipping with Ubuntu and have no idea what a backend is :)

Comment: Firstly, what is the version of your Ubuntu. Secondly, BibLaTeX backend is program that creates your citation list. It is BibTeX or biber. When using BibLaTeX you compile your `.tex` file with `(pdf)latex` and then you compile it with backend to create citation database which is used in next latex run.

Comment: Hi, sorry it is Ubuntu 12.04 and I use bibtex. So how should I compile the document? Also I have a doubt, I activated the natbib=true option for the package (we have loads of \citeauthor and \citep in the document). Should I keep the \usepackage[options]{natbib} or remove it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try not loading `natbib` via `\usepackage`. in manual it is said, that `natbib` is incompatible with BibLaTeX. I understood it that option `natbib=true` emulates `natbib` package.
For `logreq.sty`, try to find it in package administrator (i don't know the exact tool and I'm kinda lazy to reboot to Ubuntu)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6492/discussion-between-luca-cerone-and-crowley)