# Separated references sections for appendix

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib, multibib

The references in my document have the following requirements:

- My references need to appear *before* my appendices.
- My appendices contain new references. These references should **not** appear in the main references list (before the appedices). Instead, they have to appear *after* each appendix (for example, when appendix A is ended, the references related to this appendix must be shown, then appendix B should be started).

I have only one big `bib` file for both main refrences and appendices' references (separating them is almost impossible !!)

I've looked for it several days to find a solution but I was unsuccessful. I tried multibib package but it doesnt show anything.

Would someone help me please to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating different `.bib` files and loading them when needed? If you can, I'd suggest switching to `biblatex` altogether, since you can use multiple `.bib` files and assign each one to a specific section.

Comment: See also these two questions. **Biblatex *or* multibib**: [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660/4778), **Biblatex**: [Single .tex file, multiple .bib files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83794/4778).